# collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, c

I used the following:

```
gcc -c -O4 ab_test.c
```

This worked and generated `ab_test.o` without error, but

```
gcc -o ab_test ab_test.o -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

lead to error as:

```
**/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
/home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/glibc-2.18/csu/../sysdeps/x86_64/start.S:118: undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status**
```

The code is ab_test.c is as under

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_randist.h>


Main()
{
  int i, temp_int;
  char amode[30];
  char bmode[30];
  float wave_vector_y;
for(i=0; i<41; i++)
    {
        //// set wave vector ////
        wave_vector_y = i*0.005;    

        temp_int = 10000*wave_vector_y;
        sprintf(amode,"a%04d.dat",temp_int);
        sprintf(bmode,"b%04d.dat",temp_int);
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be `main` not `Main`

Comment: `Main()` -> `int main(void)`

Comment: Also it should add `return 0;` at the end.

Comment: @UniCell Can be properly omitted for `main()`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ but not `int main(void)`. The whole main should look like `int main(void){ ... return 0;}`

Comment: @UniCell No, you're wrong. It's OK to omit the `return 0;`. That's guaranteed to be the default for `main()`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ tell me you didn't said that. I hope that in the programs made by you there is a `return 0;`.How would you know that the program exit correctly?

Comment: @UniCell - it's your own styling technique. While I prefer to return a value from main, it is not required, and you could also use the C lib `exit(return code)` to specify an exit code for a void returning main entry point (I don't like it, but it's possible).

Comment: @iMoses (not exactly to `return 0`, but `return _something_`) and it's good practice.

Comment: @UniCell _"tell me you didn't said that"_ No, I'm telling you exactly that, and it's true for `main()`. Nothing hinders you to put a `return -1;` in case of an error there. But ***you can omit*** `return 0;`. As mentioned it's the default.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ not exatly `return 0;` but `return something;` if you use `int main(void)`

Answer (score 0):

Your "main" signature should be something like `int main(void)`or `int main(int argc ,char *argv[])` and not old C style syntax for `int Main()`.

Comment: _"and not old C style syntax ..."_ ?!? Uhm what?

Comment: Old C style syntax doesn't allow `int Main()`

Comment: Never said it is an acceptable signature, but not specifying the return type is old C style.

Comment: @AlterMann - `char**` is perfectly valid for the main signature.

Comment: Yes, `char **argv` and `char *argv[]` are interchangeable , but `int main(int,char**)` is not valid (variable names are omitted)

Comment: @AlterMann - that's wrong. `int main(int,char**){ return 0; }` is a perfectly valid C++ program (but not C).

Comment: @iMoses, oops, question is also tagged `C++`, sorry!! anyway `int main(int argc ,char *argv[])` is valid in both languages